# Cumulative sum of consecutive positive or negative numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a huge array of positive and negative numbers. I am trying to find cumulative sum of consecutive positive and negative numbers. The cumulative sum should restart every time the sign changes.

For example, I have

```
data = 
  {-1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, -2, -5, 3, 1, 2, 1, -1, -1, 1, 2, 4, -1, 1, 1, -1, -2, 1};
```

I want:

```
cusum = 
  {-1, 2, 5, 9, 11, 12, -2, -7, 3, 4, 6, 7, -1, -2, 1, 3, 7, -1, 1, 2, -1, -3, 1};
```

so that the result looks like

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With data being

```
data = {-1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, -2, -5, 3, 1, 2, 1, -1, -1, 1, 2, 4, -1, 1, 1, -1, -2, 1};
```

as in the OP, then do

```
Accumulate /@ SplitBy[data, Sign] // Flatten
(* {-1, 2, 5, 9, 11, 12, -2, -7, 3, 4, 6, 7, -1, -2, 1, 3, 7, -1, 1, 2, -1, -3, 1} *)
```

Comment: @ march, thank you so much. In fact, I spent almost an  hour to do it without success. I am going to leave this question so that someone in the future will not waste their time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

Since you mentioned you are working with huge arrays, you might consider using [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile). For instance, here are two possible [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile) approaches:

```
fc = Compile[{{a, _Integer}, {b, _Integer}},
    If[a b <= 0, b, a + b]
];

gc = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}},
    Module[{total = 0},
        Table[
            If[a[[i]] total <= 0,
                total = a[[i]],
                total += a[[i]]
            ],
            {i, Length[a]}
        ]
    ]
];
```

A comparison on a list with a million elements:

```
data = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, 10^6];

r1 = gc[data]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = FoldList[fc, data]; //AbsoluteTiming
r3 = Accumulate /@ SplitBy[data, Sign] // Flatten; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2 === r3
```

> {0.047799, Null}
>
> {0.072444, Null}
>
> {1.45911, Null}
>
> True

Comment: @ Carl, thank you for your time and answer. It is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
Flatten[FoldList[Plus, #] & /@ Split[data, Sign[#1] == Sign[#2] &],2]
```

Comment: @ Alucard, thank you for your time and answer. I really appreciate it.